# Create entity model Many-To-Many CodeFirst Ef6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'd like Db use Code-First [image]

What I did:

```
    public class Responses
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual AppUser AppUser { get; set; }

        public int QuestionId { get; set; } 
        public virtual Question Question { get; set; }

        public string Answer { get; set; }

    }
       
    public class Question
    {
        public int idQuestion { get; set; }
        public string TextQuestion { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Responses> Responses  { get; set; }
    }

    public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int, AppUserLogin, AppUserRole, IdentityUserClaimBase>, ICRMRepository, IEditableEntity, IEntityBase
    {
        public int idUser {get;set;}
        public ICollection<Responses> Responses { get; set; }

    }
```

next to I go to DbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Responses>()
                .HasKey(x => new {x.UserId, x.QuestionId});

            modelBuilder.Entity<Responses>()
                .HasOne(x=>x.User)
```

Cannot resolve symbol "HasOne"

what should I do if I would like get db like this?

How do I configure my association with fluent API? Or is there a better way to create the association table?

UPD
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could solve it:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int, AppUserLogin, AppUserRole, IdentityUserClaimBase>, ICRMRepository, IEditableEntity, IEntityBase
{
    public ICollection<Response> Responses { get; set; } 
}

public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TextQuestion { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Response> Responses  { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ***public int AppUserId { get; set; }***
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    
    public virtual AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }

    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

db context:

```
public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
public DbSet<Response> Responses { get; set; }
```

EF6 understand what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Change Responses class, replace AppUser property by User

```
public class Responses
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual AppUser User{ get; set; }

       ........

    }
```

and use this code for Db context

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Response>(entity =>
{
 entity.HasOne(d => User)
  .WithMany(p => p.Responses)
  .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);

 entity.HasOne(d => d.Question)
 .WithMany(p => p.Responses)
   .HasForeignKey(d => d.QuestionId;
});
```

Comment: It's dosent work. I get issue "Class name User is a not valid"

Comment: @Boris It is just a typo. You could fix it

Comment: I got it. Fix it and paste My type intead "User" I paste AppUser

Comment: @Boris Is it working now

Comment: I update My ask, see pict

Comment: I got again the same problem with. What am I doing wrong?